# Using customRequest in Ant design file upload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I am using Axios to handle the file upload. I am facing a problem showing the upload progress of the file upload. The file upload view I am using is "picture-card".

HTML

```
<Upload
  accept="image/*"
  customRequest={uploadImage}
  onChange={handleOnChange}
  listType="picture-card"
  fileList={defaultListOfFiles}
  className="image-upload-grid"
>
  {defaultListOfFiles.length >= 8 ? null : <div>Upload Button</div>}
</Upload>
```

OnChangeHandler

```
const handleOnChange = ({ file, fileList, event }) => {
  console.log(file, fileList, event);
  //Using Hooks to update the state to the current filelist
  setDefaultFileList(fileList);
  //filelist - [{uid: "-1",url:'Some url to image'}]
};
```

CustomRequest handler

```
const uploadImage = options => {

  const { onSuccess, onError, file, onProgress } = options;

  const fmData = new FormData();
  const config = {
    headers: { "content-type": "multipart/form-data" },
    onUploadProgress: event => {
      console.log((event.loaded / event.total) * 100);
      onProgress({ percent: (event.loaded / event.total) * 100 },file);
    }
  };
  fmData.append("image", file);
  axios
    .post("http://localhost:4000/upload", fmData, config)
    .then(res => {
      onSuccess(file);
      console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(err=>{
      const error = new Error('Some error');
      onError({event:error});
    });
}
```

Answer (score 39):

`antd` [`Upload`](https://ant.design/components/upload/#How-to-use-customRequest) uses [`rc-upload`](https://github.com/react-component/upload) under the hood. [`onProgress`](https://github.com/react-component/upload#customrequest) accepts only one argument. I have also used `antd` [`Progress`](https://ant.design/components/progress/) for an alternative way of showing progress. Read more about [customRequest](https://github.com/react-component/upload#customrequest).

[image: upload-progress]

**JSX**

```
import { Upload, Progress } from "antd";

const App = () => {
  const [defaultFileList, setDefaultFileList] = useState([]);
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);

  const uploadImage = async options => {
    const { onSuccess, onError, file, onProgress } = options;

    const fmData = new FormData();
    const config = {
      headers: { "content-type": "multipart/form-data" },
      onUploadProgress: event => {
        const percent = Math.floor((event.loaded / event.total) * 100);
        setProgress(percent);
        if (percent === 100) {
          setTimeout(() => setProgress(0), 1000);
        }
        onProgress({ percent: (event.loaded / event.total) * 100 });
      }
    };
    fmData.append("image", file);
    try {
      const res = await axios.post(
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
        fmData,
        config
      );

      onSuccess("Ok");
      console.log("server res: ", res);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Eroor: ", err);
      const error = new Error("Some error");
      onError({ err });
    }
  };

  const handleOnChange = ({ file, fileList, event }) => {
    // console.log(file, fileList, event);
    //Using Hooks to update the state to the current filelist
    setDefaultFileList(fileList);
    //filelist - [{uid: "-1",url:'Some url to image'}]
  };

  return (
    <div class="container">
      <Upload
        accept="image/*"
        customRequest={uploadImage}
        onChange={handleOnChange}
        listType="picture-card"
        defaultFileList={defaultFileList}
        className="image-upload-grid"
      >
        {defaultFileList.length >= 1 ? null : <div>Upload Button</div>}
      </Upload>
      {progress > 0 ? <Progress percent={progress} /> : null}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here is a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-58128062-upload-progress)

Comment: `onUploadProgress` gets fired only when the progress is complete. So event.loaded & event.total are always the same. Because of this we see the progress bar moves 100% in no time.

Comment: did you find any solution here? @TA3

Comment: @blueseal, can you pls explain this: 
onError({ err });   how is the error handed? I want to present the error to user. tnx